# How to place a label in an area outside of an SVG path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I'm creating an HTML5 canvas mapping app that uses the [D3 contour plugin](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134) to generate an SVG. I need to label the centroid of certain areas that are outside of a calculated path.

For example, I'd like to place a label inside each of the two blue regions:
[image]

The green region is an SVG path calculated by D3, and the blue "water" regions are the background showing through areas not covered by the "land" polygon.

I have used `.getBBox()` for other polygons that have D3-generated paths, but for these regions, the bounding box is the entire SVG.

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/arebe/pen/oLxGJo) demonstrates placing a label on the "land" section of SVG, using `.getBBox()` - in this example I would like to place a second label on the blue "water" section in the lower right corner.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Please provide a snippet or fiddle so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You has a concept error. getBBox works well and do what it must to do:

**Step 1**: You draw WATER

[image]

**Step 2**: Draw the land contour, layer by layer. (Overlaping WATER)

[image]

**Step 3**: get the LAND boundary box (getBBox). And put the label on the center

[image]

**Step 4**: get the WATER boundary box (getBBox). And put the label on the center

[image]

At the end you can't see the WATER label:

[image]

**Posible solution A**: Consider WATER level as another layer (modding your data)

[image]

**Posible solution B**: This is just a thought: you can create a mask from the very low layer and used to mask the WATER box as cookie cutter. I think getBBox will give you the right size the final shape.

[image]

**Recomendation**: Try it on differents browsers. Firefox has a bug with getBBox: You can see it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612118 **Not solved yet**

Comment: this is a wonderful illustration of the issue - my question is: how can I create the water layer from the existing SVG path and/or data?